# Microsoft .Net framework 4.0 for Single byte character languages

Tags: .net, sas

While installing SAS OnDemand, I am getting this error:

> The following requirments must be met before deploying your SAS Software.
>
> Microsoft.NET Framework 4.0 for Single Byte Character Languages

Can anyone help me with this error. I am using Win 7 32 bit. I have VS 2010 on my computer and I tried installing .NET framework 4.0 again, but without any result.
My friends installed this application without any probles, but I am stuck.

Comment: "Single Byte Character Languages" is quite bizarre.  You'll need to contact SAS for support.

Comment: Typing *Microsoft.NET Framework 4.0 for Single Byte Character Languages* into Google points me over to the [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Language Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23067). Not sure if it's related, though.

Comment: I would recommend opening a track with SAS technical support if you can't resolve this on your own (start [here](http://support.sas.com/) ).

Comment: Close voters, this shouldn't be closed as off-topic; it's about a tool generally used for programming (sas).

Comment: I was wondering which OnDemand product are you trying to install (e.g. Enterprise Guide)?

Comment: @YickLeung yes it is Enterprise Guid. Can you help mi fix this ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an installation issue that can only be addressed by vendor support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this, I'm not sure if I know enough to fix this since I don't know much about Microsoft.Net. You're using a Windows 32-bit system which might not be compatible with the new versions of OnDemand Enterprise Guide such as *SAS OnDemand for Academics 6.1 Enterprise Guide*. I think most of the newer SAS products only support Windows 64-bit systems and this has been the trend for other technologies as well.

But same as what Joe has suggested, you should definitely contact SAS technical support first. While I was on their website looking for solutions, I had a chat with a SAS online representative, but she didn't have the technical knowledge to resolve the issue.The transcript are as follows:

Chat Transcript http://puu.sh/5R8gd.jpg same as below:

```
info: Please wait for a site operator to respond.
info: You are now chatting with 'Pam'
Pam: Hi!  Welcome to Live Chat!  I'm here to help!
Pam: May I please have your name and company?
you: Hello
Pam: Hi!
you: I'm not actually not with a company, but I'm a student
Pam: Super, how may I help you today?
you: My friend has a problem with his installation of SAS onDeand
you: Demand*
Pam: What is the issue?
you: He has a windows 32 bit machine and it's telling his that microsoft.net framework 4.0 is missing
Pam: I think this is something he should speak with our technical support about. Let me get their contact information for you.
Pam: If you need immediate help, please call 919-677-8008. You can also open your own track by clicking here to submit your questions via our online form or emailing support@sas.com. Will that work for you?
you: Alright thanks
Pam: You are very welcome.
you: yeah that's great
Pam: They will be able to help you with the installation issue.
you: thank you
Pam: You bet!
Pam: Thank you for chatting with us!  Have a great day!
Pam: Your feedback regarding the chat experience is important to us.  I would like for you to click here  to complete a short survey when you are ready to exit the chat.
```

If you're outside North America, you still have to call the number above because their support team is located at the headquarters in the United States.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will ask support about my problems :)